# Ember access array controller's content from another controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two controllers: postsController and postController. the post route is NOT nested under posts ( I do not want to do so because I want the posts view to be replaced by the post view, not added to it.)

This is what my router looks like.

```
this.resource('posts', {path: '/'}, function(){
    // this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  });

  this.resource('post', { path: 'posts/:id' }, function(){
    this.route('show');
  }
```

Now, the postsController:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('post');
  },
})

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  testProperty: "This is a test"
})
```

And the PostController:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('post', params.id);
  },
})

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['posts'],
  percentValue: 100,
  progressBarWidth: null,

  advancePost: function(delta) {
    var that = this;
    var posts = that.get('controllers.posts');
    // debugger <-- This is where all my questions are concerned with.
    ...
  },

  actions: {
    nextPost: function() {
      this.advancePost(1);
    },
    previousPost: function() {
      this.advancePost(-1);
    },
  }
})
```

So. PostController 'needs' PostsController, and on action advancePost, needs to access PostsController's model (which is supposed to contain an array of Post Objects.) At the point where my debugger is, the variable posts accessed postsController. At this point, if I run

```
posts.get('testProperty') // => gives "This is a test", which is correct.
```

on the chrome console, I get "This is a test". So I know that I have gained access to the Posts Controller itself. However, any of the following attempts:

```
posts.get('model') // gives []??
posts.get('content') // gives []??
```

returns an empty array ( [] ).

I fail to understand why. If I have access to the Posts arrayController, why do I not have access to its data? Consequently, how would I gain access to its data?

I would greatly appreciate clarity on this.

Answer (score 0):

First, if I understand your context, I think you should rather nest `post` under `posts` by doing this :

`this.resource('posts', {path: '/'}, function(){
   this.route('post', {path: '/:id'});
});`

And then, since `posts` is your "parent" route, you no longer need to declare the `needs` dependency in your controller.

To access get your posts, apply the following in your `Route` :

`setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('posts', this.modelFor("posts").get("content"));
}`

Comment: It seems off to me too, to not route post under posts. However, the post insists on rendering as part of the posts template; I need it to replace the posts template. On each post, there is a button to go back to the list. Think imgur or 9gag, or any of the image-sharing sites. I feel that this is definitely the better approach - and I would like to facilitate it - but save for adding a 'hidden' class on every transition, I cannot think of anything. In a way I expect Ember to have some sort of ability to replace the current outlet view with a nested view; any idea how that can be done?

Comment: render your posts in `posts/index` and the detail thing in `posts/post` . That way, they will "logically" be nested but will remains siblings to each others in the templates

Answer (score 0):

You should think about the interaction patterns you want to support. Is it typical for a user to go back to the list of items they were just looking at?  Reloading posts whilst keeping the scroll position in the list they were at will be problematic. Also re-fetching from the server and tearing down and setting up the DOM has a lot more overhead than just leaving it there.

Are you intending to use animation on your transitions? Using something like liquid-fire will need both outlets rendered to perform an animation so it makes no sense to tear down the list in that case.

CSS can be used to have the nested outlet fill whatever container it is put in allowing the approach provided by Pascal Boutin  to be used.

Comment: To answer, yes it would be typical to go back. I agree that posts shouldn't be fetched repeatedly; I think nesting the route is definitely a better approach. However, save for toggling a 'hidden' class, how would I be able to replace the displayed posts view with a post view?